# Customizing an ISO to include Radeon graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, radeon, toshiba-satellite

so I recently purchased the Toshiba satellite L7775D laptop.  I wanted to install Ubuntu, but I can't even boot a livecd without the graphics card drivers for the proprietary Radeon card.  So I need to customize a livecd to include the drivers.  Could someone explain how to do this?  Thank you.

Comment: You could use an Alternate ISO and its text based installer. Not very pretty, but gets the job done. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while booting from the live cd you can add  `radeon.nomodeset=1` to the boot options so that you can boot up from the standard mesa driver, install Ubuntu from there, then install fglrx driver

OR
you can try [remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/), but I assume you have not installed ubuntu already,in that case you need to get a custom iso done from a friend having AMD card with proprietary drivers installed

also note that if you pre-install proprietary drivers it will be hard to revert to OSS drivers as fglrx diverts some files